# Save Queue to File, Then load it and compare with Original

Tags: c#, serialization, queue, compare

I have a Problem saving a Queue to a file, loading it afterwards into a new queue and then     compare the old Queue with the new Queue.

I have a simple TestMessageClass, now i want to serialize the Queue and save it to a file named test.bin. Works fine i think, but when i load the Queue into another variable and compare them, it gives me the following error:

```
Expected: equivalent to 

Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass


But was:


Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass, 
Grid.NodeTests.MessageSink_Tests.MessageSinkTests+TestMessageClass
```

If i take normal strings to enqueue it all works fine, but if i take my TestMessageClass it won´t work anymore.

```
[Serializable()]
class TestMessageClass
{
    public enum MessageType
    { 
        Broadcast,
        Unicast
    }
}

internal interface ISerializationService
{
      void Serialize(Stream outputStream, object obj);
      T Deserialize<T>(Stream inputStream);
}

public void Serialize(Stream outputStream, Object obj)
{

    IFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    serializer.Serialize(outputStream, obj);


}

public T Deserialize<T>(Stream inputStream)
{

    var result = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(inputStream);

    return (T)result;

}
[Test]
public void CompareQueue()
{
    Queue queue1 = new Queue();

    var message = new TestMessageClass();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        queue1.Enqueue(message);

    ISerializationService service = new SerializationService();

    FileStream stream = File.Open("Test.bin" , FileMode.Create , FileAccess.Write);

    service.Serialize(stream, queue1);
    stream.Close();

    FileStream stream2 = File.Open("Test.bin" , FileMode.Open ,FileAccess.Read);

    Queue queue2 = service.Deserialize<Queue>(stream2);
    stream2.Close();
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(queue1,queue2);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to implement Equals on your TestMessageClass to determine if 2 different instances are equal.  Typically you could implement the method by comparing all the properties on each instance.

When you serialize it and then deserialize it, it will create new instances, so the default Equals implementation will return false because it just compares if the instances are the same.